# What's the best Windows service to record / stream images from a webcam?

Tags: windows-7, streaming, webcam, windows-services

I have a machine running Windows 7 Home Premium with a pair of webcams attached.

I need to take a snapshot once every 5 mins or so from each camera and allow streaming of the live feed over a network.

I need this to run as a service.

What are my options?